# evil-mode '>' evil-shift-left loses selection

Tags: emacs, evil

Is there any reason that evil-mode evil-shift-left loses the selection?

I.e., I'd like the ability to hit the '>' and '<' multiple times on the selection to shift text left and right.

Here's the implementation below. Anyway to add an advice to change this behavior?

evil-commands.el

```
(evil-define-operator evil-shift-right (beg end &optional count)
  "Shift text from BEG to END to the right.
The text is shifted to the nearest multiple of `evil-shift-width'
\(the rounding can be disabled by setting `evil-shift-round').
See also `evil-shift-left'."
  :type line
  (interactive "<r><vc>")
  (let ((beg (set-marker (make-marker) beg))
        (end (set-marker (make-marker) end)))
    (dotimes (i (or count 1))
      (if (not evil-shift-round)
          (indent-rigidly beg end evil-shift-width)
        (let* ((indent
                (save-excursion
                  (goto-char beg)
                  (evil-move-beginning-of-line nil)
                  (while (and (< (point) end) (looking-at "[ \t]*$"))
                    (forward-line))
                  (if (> (point) end) 0
                    (current-indentation))))
               (offset (- evil-shift-width (mod indent evil-shift-width))))
          (indent-rigidly beg end offset))))
    (set-marker beg nil)
    (set-marker end nil)))
```

Comment: Note that even though this is handy functionality, pressing `u` to undo will make the text lowercase and needs 2x undo's to undo the indent. More recently I've taken to using the `.` to perform multiple shifts instead fo relying on the selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This overloads the current behavior to re-select (found at [djoyner/dotfiles/emacs/lisp/evil-config.el#L36-L40](https://github.com/djoyner/dotfiles/blob/888a1f0d5cdd9a15a0bfe93a96cdd1fc5d7f2d57/emacs/lisp/evil-config.el#L36-L40)).

```
; Overload shifts so that they don't lose the selection
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd ">") 'djoyner/evil-shift-right-visual)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "<") 'djoyner/evil-shift-left-visual)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map [tab] 'djoyner/evil-shift-right-visual)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map [S-tab] 'djoyner/evil-shift-left-visual)

(defun djoyner/evil-shift-left-visual ()
  (interactive)
  (evil-shift-left (region-beginning) (region-end))
  (evil-normal-state)
  (evil-visual-restore))

(defun djoyner/evil-shift-right-visual ()
  (interactive)
  (evil-shift-right (region-beginning) (region-end))
  (evil-normal-state)
  (evil-visual-restore))
```

Comment: That rocks! Just tried it. Love it!

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to the answer already provided by @avsej, but using `call-interactively` ensures evil-shift-{left,right} receives all its arguments (e.g. `COUNT`). For example,

```
(defun my-visual-shift-left ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'evil-shift-left)
  (evil-normal-state)
  (evil-visual-restore))
```

That way, you can still indent by more than one unit at a time (e.g. <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>></kbd>).